# How do I rig a model made with multiple objects?

Tags: rigging

I tried looking at some similar questions but the answers just don't work for me:(

So, my model is made of multiple objects as seen below:

[image]

They are made with planes using the "Skin" modifier, I'm somewhat new to blender. I saw something saying that I should Ctrl+P them together, which I did(In a different version of the model as I didn't want to lose the original), And it didn't work:

[image]

My question is what did I do wrong and how do I properly rig this?

Thanks:D

Comment: hello, you need to select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, press Ctrl P to parent

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the objects are not parented to the armature.

Select one of the objects, then<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the armature, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> and choose *Armature Deform*.

Keep in mind you still need to weight paint the object. You can press with automatic weights on the *Parent* menu, but the weights may not be perfect.